# Azure Service Fabric in Visual Studio - hresult : 0x80131500

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm currently trying to work on **Azure Service Fabric** in **Visual Studio 2015** but I have a **general exception (hresult : 0x80131500)** when i create a new **service fabric project**.

For example, I got this error when i create a **stateless service project**, or **anything else** coming from service fabric... Can't post screenshots of the process for now... Thing is that when I installed service fabric packages, there were errors (already installed package but not, couldn't access the package)...

Spent hours trying to resolve this problem, I tried to uninstall everything, to change from a version to another, I searched a lot for an answer but not found.
Maybe I didn't understand what is happening there, and maybe someone could help me !

Service Fabric Tools: 1.4

Visual Studio: 14.0.25431.01 Update 3

.NET framework: 4.6.1

---

**UPDATE**

Thank you everyone, Microsoft updated their packages, it seems that it was coming from them, i tried to reinstall packages again and it works now !
I don't know how this post can be marked as resolved, if someone could do it, it would be great !

Comment: 0x80131500 = System.Exception/COR_E_EXCEPTION (Base class for all exceptions in the runtime), so nothing helpful . Attach Windbg to devenv.exe (VS), when an exception occurs, run **!analyze -v** in windbg to see more details about exceptions.

Comment: Could you tell me if it's a thing like that, sorry to say that, but i'm not used to VS at this point... 

http://pastebin.com/Q1pjbQHN

Comment: I did a crash dump of devenv.exe in task manager when the exception occurs, and then openned it windbg and tried **!analyze -v** on it. When i was attaching to devenv.exe, i couldn't use VS to create the project and generate the exception, i'm not sure to be clear there... Just tell me if i'm wrong on this, thank you.

Comment: you used 64 bit task to create a dump of 32bit program. this makes debugging difficult. start VS and when now attach Windbg (start windbg (x86), press F6 in windbg, select the devenv process, click ok and now press F5 to continue VS process. Do you steps that generate the error. if VS is frozen (this means an issue occured), go back to Windbg and now run **!analyze -v** to see what is going on. if it is unrelated, press again F5 in windbg to continue VS

Comment: Ok i understood, now here is the moment of VS freezing : http://pastebin.com/WWq2DR4E

And i captured the moment after and got this : 
http://pastebin.com/VJ9tLeHq

Sorry there is a bit of french (native language) in the text, but i'm pretty sure there is no link with the error. Thank you for explanations, will help me for sure in the future !

Comment: there is a network connection close issue. my school french is limited so reading the log is difficult.

Comment: Haha really sorry, is there a way to change the language ? Not sure from where the text is coming... **Network connection close issue** in the creation of a project ? I don't know why VS would connect to create a project...

Comment: I never used Azure, so I have no real idea what VS does

Comment: I understand, fact is that i'm learning all of this in the same time, really hard to find out what does that and why it does... I will report my problem on their forum to see if it is coming from my computer (fact is that i tried on another computer) or from the version of packages... Thank you for your help, still here if you got solutions !

Comment: post your own steps to resolve it as answer and here you can mark your own reply as answer later: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft updated their packages, it seems that it was coming from them, i tried to reinstall packages again and it works now !

- Launch **Web Platform Installer** (type it in Windows run menu).
- Select Microsoft Service Fabric package.
- Install it, or update it.
- Should work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to repro this when the 3.5 .NET Framework was missing.   Specifically project creation is looking for targets files under the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 folder triggering the exception.  Need to investigate why the tooling has a dependency on the older .NEt framework.

For now to try to fix the issue, can you enable the .NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0) feature in "Control-Panel->Programs and Features-> Turn Windows features on or off" and see if it also resolves the issue for you.

Comment: I did exactly all the things you explained here, the problem still here...
Thank you for your answer, I will try to report my problem on their forum, maybe the problem isn't from my computer (but i tried on another computer). Still, if you know a solution for this problem, don't forget me !

Comment: Can you enable .NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0) from the Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off dialog.   I was able to repro the issue when files here were missing -> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727

Comment: Yes, it was already enabled when i had the issue... The problem was from **Web Platform Installer** that was not downloading well the packages for Service Fabric... But i think that you could have issues on this too...